# custom filter on each column in webgrid MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I need to implement custom column in-built filtering for each columns of webgrid MVC. Currently, all the examples have a search text box which filters out the records. However, I would like to have a filter on each column in the grid separately.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this is not feasible with the in-built MVC webgrid!